# How do I write back to a cell in a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am working through a table, row by row, processing the information.

If the particular row results in an invoice being produced, I want to write that invoice number into the cell at the end of the row.

Everything works perfectly until I get to the part where I am trying to write back that text.  The loop begins:

```
var bookingData = sheet.getRange(8, 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

//Now loop through the bookings table to get the ones that need to be invoiced
for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
  var row = bookingData[i];
  ...
```

So I have my current data in the variable **row**.  If the row has generated an invoice, I want to be able to say "now file the invoice number in cell 13 of that row", but I can't work out the syntax.

I have tried all sorts of variants on:

```
var invCell = bookingData.getCell[i][13];
invCell.setValue("TVH-" + nextInv);
```

but so far without success.  Could somebody please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`sheet.getRange(i+8,columnnumber).setValue("TVH-" + nextInv);`

Comment: Brilliant - thank you.  I knew it would be something simple - I just couldn't get there.